# animation which looks the same as in the bumble application

Tags: android

I tried to achieve animation like bumble app  but couldn't able to achieve same animation like that application so please any one guide to proceed

used these dependency for trying to achieve the bumble app function :
1.SwipableCard(https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView)
2.CardLayoutManager(https://github.com/adgvcxz/CardLayoutManager)

Answer (score 0):

By using this library we can able to achieve it..

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6889

Little bit need to customized for angel and rotation